# JAR not showing images?

Tags: java, jar, executable-jar

Ok, here's my problem:

I created a jar (something I've done many times before), but it's not working correctly. I have 3 java files in yet; usually I have one. I create objects of two of the classes in the main class; is there anything special I have to do when creating the objects? The images that I use are in a folder that is in the same folder as the JAR, so that's not a problem.

I can post code if you want/need, though I don't see how it'll do any help.

Comment: "I have 3 java files in yet; .."  Put classes in Jar files, not .java source files. "I can post code if you want/need, though I don't see how it'll do any help."  Change line 42, column 73 from a '.' to a ','.  That should fix the problem.  If my powers of mental telepathy are failing me, post an [SSCCE](http://pscode.org/sscce.html) for further help.

Comment: `though I don't see how it'll do any help.`, but if you don't know what's causing the error, how do you know what will or won't help in solving it?

Comment: @Andrew "Put classes in Jar files, not .java source files" THAT'S what I needed, thank you. I knew it was something that had to do with the multiple files. :) Thank you.

Comment: Don't neglect to accept @Andrew Thompson's answer when he posts it. Also, you have enough [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/faq) now to vote for answers you found helpful.

Comment: Sorry, was in a rush and didn't have time to do it last night; did it now though. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I have 3 java files in yet; ..

Put classes in Jar files, not .java source files.

( It surprises me that was the answer! ;)

Answer (score 1):

> The images that I use are in a folder that is in the same folder as the JAR, so that's not a problem.

Maybe it **is** a problem.

I presume that you are trying to access the images via the `Class.getResourceAsStream(...)` or something like that.  If so, the classloader will only see the image files if they are in a directory tree that is on the classpath.  The way that you described it, the image files are NOT in the JAR file, and therefore you need a separate classpath entry for the directory.

(What would really help would be if you rewrote your question in clearer English ... and using the correct terminology.  For instance: *"I create objects of two of the classes in the main class"* is nonsensical. )